# how do i setup ubuntu desktop in ec2

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-ec2, desktop

Been playing around with amazon ec2, so far I've been able to get ubuntu-desktop working  (once) although it was a random set of hacks from blogs 
ive not been able to reproduce what made it work

my setup
windows box w/- putty, NX-Nomachine, 
amazon:ubuntu 10.04 lucid ami
when i launch NX i can see the nicely rendered terminal window inside the desktop viewer, on a plain black background. previously I had tried
    sudo aptitude install ubuntu-desktop
but im unclear as to what steps are needed to view my new desktop within my image.
when i try start x - i get a user not authorized to start x-server..aborting
i've also noticed errors like 'xf860penconsole cannot open dev/tty0 [no such file or directory] ' and 
'
any thoughts about what this might be ?

Answer (score 12):

I have just set up the remote desktop of Ubuntu on Windows. I have Ubuntu Instance running on EC2. I have followed this [link](http://aws-musings.com/4-easy-steps-to-enable-remote-desktop-on-your-ubuntu-ec2-instance/). But for quick installation let me give you the commands to execute. Execute this commands one-by-one.

```
export DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
sudo -E apt-get update
sudo -E apt-get install -y ubuntu-desktop
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:freenx-team
sudo apt-get update
sudo aptitude install -y freenx
wget https://bugs.launchpad.net/freenx-server/+bug/576359/+attachment/1378450/+files/nxsetup.tar.gz
tar -xvf nxsetup.tar.gz
sudo cp nxsetup /usr/lib/nx/nxsetup
sudo /usr/lib/nx/nxsetup --install
```

Say No to password

```
sudo vi /etc/ssh/sshd_config and set PasswordAuthentication to yes
sudo /etc/init.d/ssh restart

sudo passwd ubuntu
```

download and Install the setup NX client on the respective OS from [here](http://www.nomachine.com/download.php)

Note: if you get error like

gpg: requesting key D018A4CE from hkp server keyserver.ubuntu.com
gpgkeys: HTTP fetch error 7: couldn't connect to host
gpg: no valid OpenPGP data found.
gpg: Total number processed: 0

then exeucte this command

```
gpg --ignore-time-conflict --no-options --no-default-keyring --secret-keyring /etc/apt/secring.gpg --trustdb-name /etc/apt/trustdb.gpg --keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg --primary-keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv F3A662B57D580D3A2E98E5152A8E3034D018A4CE | sudo apt-key add
```

Comment: thanks, when I tried this though on a clean ubuntu instance NX client fails saying "Failed to load session gnome-fallback".

Comment: Missing part, solving "Failed to load session gnome-fallback", is shared by user1088973 below...

Answer (score 4):

I am using 12.04 and have found the need for one additional line

sudo apt-get install gnome-session-fallback

Answer (score 3):

A little late, but as a reference for others.

More detail installation:
http://michaelhallsmoore.com/blog/Desktop-Ubuntu-in-Amazon-EC2-The-Right-Way

Just the basics steps:
http://aws-musings.com/4-easy-steps-to-enable-remote-desktop-on-your-ubuntu-ec2-instance/

The two use FreeNX Server.

Answer (score 3):

I got better results on Oneiric Ocelot using the steps below derived from [Anand Soni's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10383821/2882) (which I up-voted and hope you will too).   Anand's is probably better for Precise onward.

```
export DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
sudo -E apt-get update
sudo -E apt-get install -y ubuntu-desktop

wget http://64.34.173.142/download/3.5.0/Linux/nxclient_3.5.0-7_i386.deb
wget http://64.34.173.142/download/3.5.0/Linux/nxnode_3.5.0-9_i386.deb
wget http://64.34.173.142/download/3.5.0/Linux/FE/nxserver_3.5.0-11_i386.deb
sudo dpkg -i nxclient_3.5.0-7_i386.deb 
sudo dpkg -i nxnode_3.5.0-9_i386.deb 
sudo dpkg -i nxserver_3.5.0-11_i386.deb

sudo /usr/NX/bin/nxserver --status
sudo sed -i 's/PasswordAuthentication\ no/PasswordAuthentication\ yes/g' /etc/ssh/sshd_config
sudo service ssh restart
sudo passwd ubuntu
```

Note there are i386 and amd64 versions of NX Free Edition downloads from NoMachine.  Check [their download pages](http://www.nomachine.com/select-package.php?os=linux&id=1) for the right links for the wget commands and unpacking steps in the middle section above.

Comment: brilliant, worked fantastically when the much higher above did not. thanks

Answer (score 2):

I set mine up with NoMachine and with mounting to AWS FSx Windows SMB share.

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt -y upgrade
sudo apt install ubuntu-desktop
```

Transfer nomachine package to instance via WinSCP

```
sudo dpkg -i nomachine_6.10.12_1_amd64.deb 
sudo mkdir .nx
sudo mkdir .nx/config 
sudo cp -p .ssh/authorized_keys .nx/config/authorized.crt
sudo vi /etc/ssh/sshd_config
```

*Hit i for insert*

```
Set Password Authentication yes
```

*Hit esc to get out of insert mode*

```
:wq! to save
```

then, to set password for ubuntu account:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/ssh reload
sudo passwd ubuntu
```

to add new user:

```
sudo useradd newuser
```

to add user to the admin rights group:

```
usermod -aG sudo newuser
```

and this set new user password:

```
sudo passwd newuser
```

For FSx mounting the following is needed:

```
sudo apt-get install cifs-utils
```

then you have to edit the file ".smbcredentials" with the command:

```
vi ~/.smbcredentials
```

*Hit i for insert*

Paste the following information:

```
username=USERNAME
password=PASSWORD
domain=DOMAIN
```

*Hit esc to get out of insert mode*

```
:wq! to save
```

then in shell user prompt:

```
chmod 0600 ~/.smbcredentials
sudo mkdir /mnt/share
```

finally you have to edit  "/etc/fstab" followion teese instructions:

sudo vi /etc/fstab
use:

> $ to go to the end of the line in VI
>   i to insert
>   move to the next line and paste the following

```
//IPADDRESS/share /mnt/share cifs credentials=/home/ubuntu/.smbcredentials 0 0
```

*
Hit esc to get out of insert mode
    :wq! to save
*
Remeber to execute:

```
sudo mount -a
```

To mount the FSx share