# Install and make tkinter work on AWS EC2 instance

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-ec2, tkinter

I am desperately trying to make tkinter work on my EC2 instance.

I just want to be able to execute this line in python:

```
from tkinter import *
```

or this one for older version as from what I understood before python 3.x you had to use a capital T

```
from Tkinter import *
```

Right now both these commands return this:

```
ImportError: No module named _Tkinter
```

Here are the steps I took and what I found in my research:

- The python version currently running on my instance is python 2.6.8, thinking that tkinter might not come with this version I decided to install python version to 3.2 (keeping 2.6.8) using this http://www.hosting.com/support/linux/installing-python-3-on-centosredhat-5x-from-source/
- Then running python 3.2 I ran in the same problem it tells me no module called tkinter.
- I then tried to install tkinter using a lot of different commands:

  yum install tkinter

  yum install Tkinter

  yum install python-tk

  yum install python3-tk

  yum install tk-devel

  yum install gtk2-devel

  yum install pygtk2-devel

All of these give me the same result:

```
No package (name of the package) available.
```

Also in my python 3.2 folder in /opt (the second one I have installed) there is a folder called tkinter but it still seems that somehow python3 does not see it.

What am I missing? Whys can't I import tkinter when I am in python?

Comment: Since EC2 instances are server oriented and typically lack an X-server, if you could install a Tkinter application, where would you display it?

Comment: Yes this makes sense, I did not thought about it, Thank you!

Comment: Some Python libs need tkinter despite the display may not even be used.

Comment: @GuillaumeChevalier things like Matplotlib don't actually *need* Tkinter - they're just designed to take advantage of it, and expect it by default. See e.g. https://help.pythonanywhere.com/pages/TkinterPygameEtc .

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40675417

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After the previous answers I realized why it was not working so I made it work using an EC2 Ubuntu instance and doing the following:

```
  export DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
  sudo -E apt-get update
  sudo -E apt-get install -y ubuntu-desktop
  sudo add-apt-repository ppa:freenx-team
  sudo apt-get update
  sudo aptitude install -y freenx
  wget https://bugs.launchpad.net/freenxserver/+bug/576359/+attachment/1378450/+files/nxsetup.tar.gz
  tar -xvf nxsetup.tar.gz
  sudo cp nxsetup /usr/lib/nx/nxsetup
  sudo /usr/lib/nx/nxsetup --install
```

Then said no when asked for a password and did:

```
  sudo vi /etc/ssh/sshd_config and set PasswordAuthentication to yes
  sudo /etc/init.d/ssh restart
  sudo passwd ubuntu
  sudo apt-get install gnome-session-fallback
```

Once this was done I installed NX client on my local machine.
All this thanks to [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5132575/how-do-i-setup-ubuntu-desktop-in-ec2)

Connected to my new server where I was able to install python-tk like that:

```
 sudo apt-get install python-tk
```

And now I can use tkinter on my instance :)

Answer (score 4):

Tkinter requires a display. Unless you can somehow access a desktop on the AWS instance, you won't be able to load tkinter, much less use it.

Comment: This makes sense. I did not thought about this at all but you are totally right I can not use tkinter in this case...