# Install Tkinter On Amazon Linux

Tags: python, linux, amazon-ec2, tkinter

I am working on an Amazon Linux ec2 machine. When I try to run a Python script inside a virtualenv, I get the following message:

```
File "/home/sp/Envs/crispor/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/externals/six.py", line 80, in _import_module
__import__(name)
ImportError: No module named Tkinter
```

As I understand Tkinter should have been a part of the Python installation. But somehow it is not. These do not work -

```
sudo yum install python-tk
sudo yum install tkinter
```

How do I install Tkinter? Or should I be doing that at all give it should have been a part of the Python installation?

---

<sub>See also: ["UserWarning: Matplotlib is currently using agg, which is a non-GUI backend, so cannot show the figure." when plotting figure with pyplot on Pycharm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56656777) .</sub>

Comment: As I know `Amazon Linux ec2` works as `headless` machine - it means without monitor - (and without Graphical Environment) so it can't display any GUI - even Tkinter.

Comment: That's true. Neither do I want to display any GUI. But one of the modules in the project does this: 
`import matplotlib.pylab as plt`. This cascades to importing Tkinter.

Comment: I use X forwarding from EC2 instances so Tkinter could be useful

Answer (score 34):

You don't want (and probably you can't) install tkinter in that server. Configure matplotlib to use a non-interactive backend instead.

Put this in [your `matplotlibrc` file](http://matplotlib.org/users/customizing.html#the-matplotlibrc-file):

```
backend : agg
```

**UPDATE** This should not be necessary for matplotlib >= 3.0.0, according to the [documentation](https://matplotlib.org/users/whats_new.html#improved-default-backend-selection) "[h]eadless linux servers (identified by the DISPLAY env not being defined) will not select a GUI backend".

Comment: File location: /usr/local/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/mpl-data/matplotlibrc 
However, if you update matplotlib you will lose your edits.
-- There are instructions to make a copy of the file so you dont lose your edits.

Answer (score 14):

to add to @Goyo. you can switch the mode to agg in code as well.

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('agg',warn=False, force=True)
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
print "Switched to:",matplotlib.get_backend()
```

Answer (score 2):

Could you give python version information?

1- Try to install this:

```
yum install python-tools
```

This package uses tkinder so can help.

2- If you use python3:

```
sudo yum install python3-tkinter
```

3- Download and install the package:
http://rpm.pbone.net/index.php3?stat=3&search=python27-tkinter&srodzaj=3&dist[]=79

Comment: I tried `sudo yum install python-tools`. It tells me 'No package python-tools available'

Comment: Try: yum install python-setuptools

Comment: python-setuptools is already installed on the machine.
`Package python26-setuptools-12.2-1.32.amzn1.noarch already installed and latest version`
Although the Python inside the virtualenv is Python2.7