# AWS EMR - How to automatically edit file on all slave nodes?

Tags: python, matplotlib, edit, amazon-emr, worker

I am running a Python script on all slave nodes of an AWS EMR cluster. I need to configure matplotlib to use non-interactive backend on each slave node, otherwise I will run into an error ([detailed description provided here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40675417/install-tkinter-on-amazon-linux))

My current solution is to manually ssh into each slave node and to manually edit /usr/local/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/mpl-data/matplotlibrc:

```
backend : agg
```

Obviously, this approach is very time-consuming and inefficient.

Can anyone provide a small (pseudo) code snippet which performs this task automatically on all slave nodes?

Comment: Is it the same script that you run on all nodes? In that case the script itself could set the backend to `"Agg"`.

Comment: Yes, the python script to be executed is the same on all nodes. Good idea actually to set the backend from the python script, I will look into it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Simplest solution is to provide a shell script via [bootstrap action](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ManagementGuide/emr-plan-bootstrap.html) after Amazon EMR launches the instance:

```
#! /bin/sh
sudo sed -i 's/TkAgg/agg/g' /usr/local/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/mpl-data/matplotlibrc
```