# How do I install tkinter on an Amazon Linux EC2 instance?

Tags: python, amazon-ec2, tkinter

I am working on an EC2 instance with Amazon linux and python 3.5.
I have a package which at some point imports `tkinter` directly (differing from this question: [Install Tkinter On Amazon Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40675417/install-tkinter-on-amazon-linux) where it's imported by `matplotlib`).

Let's say I don't want to modify this script, is there a way to install `tkinter`outside of Anaconda (because I know that it works with Anaconda, since someone else is able to use `tkinter` with Anaconda).

I have checked the presence in `yum search` and did not really understand how to build it from source.

Answer (score 0):

This previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18705042/install-and-make-tkinter-work-on-aws-ec2-instance) goes into some detail on how to get it to install. With it being a headless Linux there's some additional hoops to jump through to get it to actually install.

Comment: I feel like it's a complicated overhead + it uses Ubuntu which I am not.