# No module named tkinter on amazon ec2 centOS

Tags: python, linux, matplotlib, amazon-ec2, centos

I have a python code that has following imports:

`from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt`

It internally calls `tkinter`. I am using **Amazon EC2 server having CentOS** on it. I cannot install tkinter, as OS is headless (no GUI). [This link seems to be solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18705042/install-and-make-tkinter-work-on-aws-ec2-instance), but it is for Debian OS and does not work for CentOS.

I tried installing desktop referring [this link](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/181503/how-to-install-desktop-environments-on-centos-7#181504), but that too doesn't work. It gives warning as "WARNING: group GNOME Desktop does not exists." when I ran command `yum -y groups install "GNOME Desktop"`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming that you don't want a GUI at all, but let matplotlib produce images on your server, the following might help:

**Using a backend without interactive elements should not require tkinter to be present at all.**

From the [documentation](https://matplotlib.org/faq/usage_faq.html#what-is-a-backend):

> There are two types of backends: user interface backends [...] and hardcopy backends to make image files (PNG, SVG, PDF, PS; also referred to as “non-interactive backends”).

Two ways to set the backend (also taken from the link above):

1. The backend parameter in your matplotlibrc file (see [Customizing matplotlib](https://matplotlib.org/users/customizing.html#customizing-matplotlib)):

   ```
   backend : Agg
   ```
2. Inside the script

   ```
   import matplotlib
   matplotlib.use('Agg')
   ```

   If you use the `use()` function, this must be done before importing matplotlib.pyplot.

Possible non-interactive backends:

[image]